# JBlend with LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midp

I have made some applications on J2ME using LWUIT, CLDC 1.1, MIDP 2.0 and they are working great on Nokia handsets.

But when I tried to install these applications on Huawei G7206 (JBlend) some of the applications gives error (NOT SUPPORTED) and some crashes without displaying anything.

I have tested an application without LWUIT and it worked.

My question is,
what is the issue?

Either JBlend does not support LWUIT? or I have to downgrade my applications (I mean to remove some features)?

Does anyone know the limitations to work with JBlend?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested your applications on other devices?

Confirm that your jad doesn't include any other hidden requirements, jblend generally works with LWUIT but some VM's don't handle the full LWUIT properly and require an obfuscated application or similar hacks.

Comment: Is there any alternate sdk or anything for application development for Huawei handsets? and what do you mean by obfuscated application?

Comment: I am unaware of a Huawei SDK. You should turn on obfuscation in the Netbeans project properties section to see if the size of the jar is the problem with this device. Also try checking the LWUIT demo to see if it works on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we use LWUIT in application the size of the application increase because of the jar file which we add in it. By obfuscation we can reduce the size of .jar file. And can become able to run in device.
Please try of obfuscate the application. You might get the solution of your problem